# Show $R_\mathbb{V}$ is a linear operator, find its standard matrix, and find all vectors such that $R_\mathbb{V} \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb {V}$ be the linear subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined as 
$$\mathbb{V}=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
x_4
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{V}: x_1+x_2+2x_3-x_4=0 \right \}$$
let $P_\mathbb{V}:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb{V}$, let $R_\mathbb{V}:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be the function such that $$\mathbf{x}\rightarrow \mathbf{x}+2(P_\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{x})$$
for every vector $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^4$. Show that $R_\mathbb{V}$ is a linear operator, find its standard matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
R_\mathbb{V}
\end{bmatrix}$, and find all vectors $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}
R_\mathbb{V}
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$.

I've started by having $$\mathbb{V}=span\left \{  {\begin{bmatrix} -1\\  1\\  0\\  0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -2\\  0\\  1\\  0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1\\  0\\  0\\  1 \end{bmatrix}}\right \}\Rightarrow A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I then computed, $\begin{bmatrix}P_\mathbb{V}\end{bmatrix}=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and worked from there. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct.

For the last question, though, you don't need the matrix: for a vector $v=a+b$ with $a\in V,\, b\perp V$, from the original definition of $R_V$, when will $R_V(v)=v$?

You can also figure out what transformation is $R_V$ geometrically.